# Using DSLink without DG Lux

Tags: java, opc

I have two machines. One is a windows machine while the other is a Linux machine. The scenario is as follows:

Windows machine hosts a Matrikon OPC server which has data tags configured.

Linux machine is the client. I want to receive data from OPC and send it via mqtt in Python code to cloud. However, I do not want to use DGLux for this as there is some dependency on Python code. After searching I came across this [java implementation](https://github.com/IOT-DSA/dslink-java-opc). I was planning of using this to get the data by calling java executable in python code and then utilizing the values. However, I cannot understand how to configure the matrikon OPC server address in this Java code.

Can someone guide me if this is the right approach to this problem or should I go for some other work around?

Comment: Check if you can use OPC UA with Matrikon. Then your choices for the development in Linux will be much broader.

Comment: Ok Jouni. I will try that.